How can sqladminuser in synapse get access to Lakehousedb tables?
I have some tables in a lakehouse database based on files in adls created by synapse link. I want to access those file with a system user. How can I achieve this?
Currently I get credential missing error.
I tried to access the lakehouse database from SSMS using admin user and got that issue.
Cannot find the CREDENTIAL '
https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/dataverse-xxxx/deltalake/table_partitioned'
, because it does not exist or you do not have permission.


can you add what you tried and error you are facing?

edited the question


How can sqladminuser in synapse get access to Lakehousedb tables?

AFAIK it's not possible to access the Lakehouse db tables from SSMS when you login through SQL credentials.
As per this, while Creating Lakehouse db tables we need  Storage Blob Data Contributor permissions data lake because this tables are external tables for which we need access on the storage.
If you want to access Lakehouse db tables from SSMS you need to use azure Entra authentication:


This is right, but actually i want to further create a Linked Server that connects with the lakehouse db with on prem and for it i will need a Us as it isn't supporting MFA.
